# How to setup Shopify GDPR webhooks in node.js

Tags: node.js, shopify, webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I have developed an app for shopify and now I am trying to setup the GDPR webhooks.

How do I access the GDPR webhooks routes and test them? Do I need to create a specific route for this or just use the function that shopify provided?

Shopify provides a `gdpr.js` file with some pre-configuration snippets, and we have to return status 200 for all of them, I have tried to access these routes with postman and inside the shopify, requesting the customers data, but with no success.

The code:

```
import { DeliveryMethod } from "@shopify/shopify-api";

/**
 * @type {{[key: string]: import("@shopify/shopify-api").WebhookHandler}}
 */
export default {
  /**
   * Customers can request their data from a store owner. When this happens,
   * Shopify invokes this webhook.
   *
   * https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/webhooks/configuration/mandatory-webhooks#customers-data_request
   */
  CUSTOMERS_DATA_REQUEST: {
    deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
    callbackUrl: "/api/webhooks",
    callback: async (topic, shop, body, webhookId) => {
      const payload = JSON.parse(body);
      // Payload has the following shape:
      // {
      //   "shop_id": 954889,
      //   "shop_domain": "{shop}.myshopify.com",
      //   "orders_requested": [
      //     299938,
      //     280263,
      //     220458
      //   ],
      //   "customer": {
      //     "id": 191167,
      //     "email": "john@example.com",
      //     "phone": "555-625-1199"
      //   },
      //   "data_request": {
      //     "id": 9999
      //   }
      // }
    },
  },
```

This code was invoked by `index.js` here:

```
app.post(
  shopify.config.webhooks.path,
  shopify.processWebhooks({ webhookHandlers: GDPRWebhookHandlers })
);
```

I have found some tutorials online, but it seems that the project has been updated, and they don't work anymore.

Also I have followed the shopify documentation (https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/webhooks/configuration/mandatory-webhooks), but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike normal webhooks, where you make an API call to create the webhook by topic, and then provide an endpoint where you authenticate it and process it, for the GDPR calls, you provide the endpoint in the App setup screen. Shopify then takes care of issuing the data. So the only real difference here, is you do not create the webhooks with an API call. You just provide the endpoint.

So if you can handle a webhook you create, this is the same. Just code up the routes you set in the admin for your App, and process them as any other webhook from the store.